# Filling datatable based on custom XML nodes

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, gridview, datatable

i need to show my xml in a gridview using datatable.
My XML is composed in this way:

[Click here to see the XML](https://pastebin.com/6X6U2zCg)

Now i am getting data in this way:

```
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(@"path\MyXml.xml"); //Percorso file xml

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            foreach (XmlNode xns in doc.SelectSingleNode("Settembre"))
            { 
                    string tagName = xns.Name; 
                    if (!dt.Columns.Contains(tagName))
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add(tagName); 
                    }

            }
```

With this part of the code i add my columns based on the child tags of "Settembre" (e.g. "ven_01") and this works.

Then i am writing stuff (the innerText of the child tags of the child tags of "Settembre", e.g. "Mattina_Turno_1" in "ven_01") into the cells in this way

```
     DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            foreach (XmlNode xns in doc.SelectSingleNode("Settembre"))
            {
                    dr[xns.Name] = xns.InnerText; 
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dr); 

            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

And this works too but what i want to do is display a first columns made of the parent node of the innerText as rows name in first column first cell for each row (the max of them are 3, to explain better are the tag "Mattina_Turno1", "Mattina_Turno_2"  and "Pomeriggio" , inside them can be some innerText)

This is what i have tried to do for a while.
Also since the rows name are only 3 and the columns name can be more than 3 i'd like to revert them, so, if it is possible, to display the rows name in the columns header(so "Mattina_Turno1", "Mattina_Turno_2"  and "Pomeriggio" instead) and as rows name the "Settembre" child tags (e.g. "ven_01").

I hope i made me understandable

Please do not mark as duplicated because i searched a lot on the web and have not found a solution, so please do not downvote and mark as duplicated, it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by doing this:

```
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Data");
            foreach (XmlNode xns in doc.DocumentElement)
            {
                if (xns.Name == "Settembre") ///IMPLEMENTARE SELEZIONE AUTOMATICA DEL MESE IMPORTANTE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 

                    foreach (XmlNode xn in xns)
                    {
                        string tagName = xn.Name;
                        var a = dt.Rows.Add(tagName);
                     //   int index_of_a = dt.Rows.IndexOf(a);

                    }
            }
            dt.Columns.Add("Mattina Turno 1");
            dt.Columns.Add("Mattina Turno 2");
            dt.Columns.Add("Pomeriggio");


            expo_days.DataSource = dt;
            expo_days.DataBind();

            foreach (XmlNode xns in doc.DocumentElement)
            {
                if (xns.Name == "Settembre") ///IMPLEMENTARE SELEZIONE AUTOMATICA DEL MESE IMPORTANTE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 

                    foreach (XmlNode xn in xns)
                    {
                        string tagName = xn.Name;
                        var a = dt.Rows.Add(tagName);
                        //   int index_of_a = dt.Rows.IndexOf(a);
                        DataRow[] rows = dt.Select("Data = '"+tagName+"'");

                        foreach (XmlNode xna in xn)
                        { //sistemare le celle in base alla colonna della gridview
                            if(xna.Name == "Mattina_Turno_1") //here i specify in wich column is the "Mattina_Turno_1" and fill in that cell, and so on
                            expo_days.Rows[dt.Rows.IndexOf(rows[0])].Cells[3].Text = xna.InnerText;
                            if (xna.Name == "Mattina_Turno_2")
                                expo_days.Rows[dt.Rows.IndexOf(rows[0])].Cells[4].Text = xna.InnerText;
                            if (xna.Name == "Pomeriggio")
                                expo_days.Rows[dt.Rows.IndexOf(rows[0])].Cells[5].Text = xna.InnerText;

                        }


                    }
            }
```